# Remove flickering on remvoveAllElements + addElement in a group

Tags: apache-flex

I am adding and removing elements dynamically in a flex application

When adding an removing items in flex component there is a flickering happening on the screen(Not all the Time only on first loading of the application). On research I understood that this is because of the time delay for two updates. One for removeAllElements and other for addElement. Is there any way to make it as one update to remove the flickering issue?
thanks

Comment: Usually when you're adding/removing elements to a Group, you should be using a List or a DataGroup instead, because (a) it's better optimized for performance, (b) it takes care of the dirty stuff (like grouping rendering operations) for you and hence (c) there's a lot less code for you to write. That's about all I can say given the description you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use DataGroup as a base class for list components. The huge benefit of it is that it has virtual layout. What means if you have 1000 items in your list, framework will create only items which can be fit in current screen ( for example 20 ). And than reuse them when user scroll list. So most likely using DataGroup will solve you problem.